# PHP: Retrieving an image from database using variable. Showing broken image icon

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I know this sounds like it's really easy and it probably is but I can't seem to get it working. My question is how do you retrieve an image from a database where I am very sure I have the right directory set out. The main thing I am trying to do is display an image from the database if certain options are selected. I am very sure I have the database connection right, the variables and all fine too.
I have the php code spread out over two files.
Note: It is elseif because there is an IF statement before it

Here is the relevant code:

```
elseif ($MakeLeftvar == 'Mitsubishi1' && $ModelLeftvar == 'Lancer1' && $YearLeftvar == '1973 - 1979') {
while ($MitFetchImg1 = mysql_fetch_array($MitStateImg1)) {
}
```

Here is the image being retrieved:

`<img src="<?php echo($MitFetchImg1[0]); ?>" height="100" width="100" >`

Here is where the fetching of the database table is made.

```
$MitStateImg1 = mysql_query("SELECT Images FROM Mitsubishi_Images");
```

Here is the screenshot of the mysql:[image]

All help is welcome and greatly appreciated. Please no mockery if it is very easy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't access the cell value via `[0]`, use `<?php echo $MitFetchImg1['Images']; ?>`

Also mysql_* functions are deprecated, use PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that mysql_fetch_array has been deprecated as of 5.5 and removed on 7. With that being said, are you sure what you are getting back from the call to mysql_fetch_array is a numeric array? This function could also return an associative array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry

Comment: basically, a call to the function mysql_fetch_array() could return you an arran such as `array( 0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar' );` or an associative array such as `array( 'foo' => 'bar')` try passing a second param to your function call as such: `mysql_fetch_array($MitStateImg1, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Comment: Are you sure that row exists? The query result says: `Showing rows 0 - 0 ...` That means the query returned no results.

Comment: Positive. Just re-created it the exact same way too... Not sure if it matters but the data-types for the columns are... ID: Int(255). Name: varchar(100) and Images: varchar(500). Not sure what the images one is supposed to be if that helps. The table is under a database which has another table which shows the mitsubishi makes, models, and years. Depending on which make, model and year is selected (as stated) an image will show up representing the car.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT Images FROM Project1.Mitsubishi_Images` If your database name is Project1. Otherwise, put the correct db name followed by a period (.) and the table name